# Calling variables from main method

Tags: java, variables, methods, program-entry-point

I have question based on the following code:

```
public class LoginCaptchaChrome {   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String tc = args[0];
        String address = args[1];
        String test_data = args[2];
        String test_result = args[3];   

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Lam Chio Meng\\Desktop\\work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");     
        //Do other stuff
        }

    //runTest is called from a different class
    public static void runTest(String string0, String string, String string1) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        WebDriver login = new ChromeDriver();       
        System.out.println(login);

        login.get(address);
        //Do other things
   }
}
```

I am getting values for `tc,address,test_data` and `test_result` from arguments passed during execution via command prompt. Now, I want to pass the `address`  values to `login.get(address)` which is located in the runTest method.

I am unable to do that for now as I know that for this to happen, the variable `address` has to be declared outside the main method. I can't declare `address` variable outside the main method as it is receiving arguements from command prompt. Bear in mind that the method runTest is already assigned to accept values from another method from different class. Hope to have advise from you guys on how to pass the `address` values from main method to the `address` variable in runTest method.

Comment: "I can't declare address variable outside the main method as it is receiving arguements from command prompt.", - how the assignment of the variable in the `main` method restricts it from being declared as a field?

Comment: Hi user, thank you for your feedback. I believe this is because if I declare them outside the main method, I won't be able to accept arguements passed on during execution from command prompt. Does this help in clarifying? My apologies if I fell short in this. Basically, I will be exporting this  code to jar file and will execute by virtue of java -jar c:\Test\LoginCaptchaChrome test1 www.test.com c:\testdata\data.xlsx c:\testresult\result.xlsx

Comment: "if I declare them outside the main method, I won't be able to accept arguements passed on during execution from command prompt.", - why?

Comment: I believe it's because it's located outside of the method which is passing the arguement ? That is all I could think of. Kindly correct me

Comment: @lamCM: check my answer to see how you can use static field to serve your purpose.

Comment: hi faizan, tq so much for your feedback. Let me digest your solutions and I will feedback to you ASAP. Thank you so much for your effort by the way.

Comment: @IamCM Any feedback?

Comment: @faizan I don't know why everybody is suggesting static fields and methods. Why not creating an object and handling the logic there?

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer same thing.

Comment: @rpax Because, as far as I understood the problem, IamCM would then need a Singleton object, which would be so different then. But feel free to suggest it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer the object doesn't need to be singleton. For example: 
` runTest()` can be a method, and the object takes the parameters `String string0, String string, String string1` in the constructor. Anyway, I don't understand why the -1's there. The answers solve the problem stated in the question.+1 to both of you.

Comment: @rpax It's because of the requirement *"Bear in mind that the method runTest is already assigned to accept values from another method from different class."* --- and thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @IamCM  where do you initialize the class which calls `LoginCaptchaChrome.runTest()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a field in your `class LoginCaptchaChrome`. Declare a static field which you can access in the main method.

Remember non-static fields need an instance of the class (an object) to be accessed, static fields don't need an instance and can be accessed by a static context.

Now some code example:

```
public class LoginCaptchaChrome {   

    public static Optional<String> addressOptional = Optional.empty

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String tc = args[0];
        String address = args[1];
        String test_data = args[2];
        String test_result = args[3];


        //using Optional since it will simply handling value not present cases
        addressOptional = Optional.of(args[4]);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Lam Chio Meng\\Desktop\\work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");     
        //Do other stuff
        }

    //runTest is called from a different class
    public static void runTest(String string0, String string, String string1) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        WebDriver login = new ChromeDriver();       
        System.out.println(login);
        //Using this you throw an error when no address is supplied via cmd ,
        //if address is supplied then you will get it here
        login.get(addressOptional.orElseThrow(()->new NoSuchElement("address is not provided")))


        //Do other things
   }
}
```

Read about optional in java 8 if you are not familiar, it can help you avoid nulls and adopt a more functional approach.

[Optional documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Comment: Why (mis)use `Optional` if the `address` is in reality mandatory? - One could as well just throw the Exception manually using an `if`or use assertions. -- Additionally, your check using `Optional` already fails, if it was set to an empty String `""`.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer : Good sight Mark, I did not realise it will fail with `""`, As such I think your approach to use an if and check the conditions is a better idea. Also my primary objective in answering was to get the idea of using static field across. Using Optional is obviously optional (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple: Create static field in `LoginCaptchaChrome`:  `[public|private] static String address;`

```
public class LoginCaptchaChrome {

    static String address = "";   // <-- private if only set from main, otherwise public

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String tc = args[0];
        address = args[1];
        String test_data = args[2];
        String test_result = args[3];   

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Lam Chio Meng\\Desktop\\work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");     
        //Do other stuff
    }

    //runTest is called from a different class
    public static void runTest(String string0, String string, String string1) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        WebDriver login = new ChromeDriver();       
        System.out.println(login);

        login.get(address);
        //Do other things
   }
}
```

An other option is to use *System properties* in `main()`

```
System.setProperty("LoginCaptchaChrome.address", address);
```

or on command line:

```
-DLoginCaptchaChrome.address=<address>`
```

and use it at the login

```
login.get(System.getProperty("LoginCaptchaChrome.address"));
```

HTH